# Разбор по составу слова "тридцать"

Tags: словообразование

Как разобрать слово "тридцать" по составу?

Comment: Когда о чем-то просите, принято говорить "пожалуйста".

Answer (score 1):

"Три-" - корень;
"-дцать-" - суффикс;
нулевое окончание.

Числительные от «одиннадцати» до «девятнадцати», а также «двадцать», «тридцать» в современном русском языке являются простыми (http://www.traktat.com/language/book/chisl/tipc.php).

Answer (score 0):

Слово "тридцать" обозначает три над десятью, т.е. три десятка. Корень - тр -, окончание 
- и-, суффикс - дцать -, окончание - нулевое. Это сложное числительное. Но, возможно, в современном языке и сейчас рассматривается уже как суффикс.

Answer (score -1):

Три - корень, дцать - корень. Нулевое окончание. Сложное числительное.